# Weird layout issue when returning to main_app from mounted ::Engine blog / Rails 4 | Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a weird layout issue and unfortunately am not sure where to start investigating. The situation is the following. The website I experience this issue with is a rails 4 app and I recently added a monologue blog as mounted engine to it.

The websites header looks like this on initial load ...
[image]

Next I navigate to the blog, which uses a similar, but different header. When I return from the blog to my main page via link, the header suddenly looks like this ...
[image]

You see the right portion of the header is all messed up and I am not sure why. A page refresh resolves the issue, but I'd like to understand and fix the actual problem.

To give you a bit more to work with -- the page uses bootstrap-sass, the header is written in haml and the login-portion on the right is actually a partial.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
-H